# Angular detect scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a quite simple navigation system built with Angular.
My main controller generates the menu.

```
<nav class="{{active}}" ng-click= "">
        <a href="#a" class="home" ng-click= "active='home'">Home</a>
        <a href="#b" class="projects" ng-click= "active='projects'">Projects</a>
        <a href="#c" class="services" ng-click= "active='services'">Services</a>
        <a href="#d" class="contact" ng-click= "active='contact'">Contact</a>
    </nav>
```

Each link goes to a page part, flagged by an anchor.

Is there any way of detecting if the user has scrolled upon an anchor tag and highlight the matched menu item?
Furthermore, is it valid as a code technique to bind click event on the menu items to achieve a smoother scrolling?
Full example: http://jsfiddle.net/4VLLc/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Angular-ui](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/#/scrollfix) has [Scrollfix directive](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils/tree/master/modules/scrollfix).

> Add a 'ui-fixed' class to elements when the page scrolls past them
>
> Make elements sticky, or simply appear different after scrolling past
>   a certain point
>
> You can optionally pass a number to ui-scrollfix which would override
>   the detected y-offset of the element. Values can be either absolute
>   600 or offset from the calculated value -50 or +100.